# 2x nested Tensorflow custom layers results in zero trainable parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a series of custom Tensorflow (version `2.4.1`) layers and am running into a problem where the model summary shows zero trainable parameters. Below is a series of examples showing how everything is fine until I add in the last custom layer.

Here are the imports and custom classes:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Input, ReLU, 
                                     Layer)

class basic_conv_stack(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides):
        super(basic_conv_stack, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides, padding='same')
        self.bn1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = ReLU()

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x
    
class basic_residual(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides):
        super(basic_residual, self).__init__()
        self.bcs1 = basic_conv_stack(filters, kernel_size, strides)
        self.bcs2 = basic_conv_stack(filters, kernel_size, strides)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.bcs1(x)
        x = self.bcs2(x)
        return x
    
class basic_module(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides):
        super(basic_module, self).__init__()
        self.res = basic_residual
        self.args = (filters, kernel_size, strides)
    
    def call(self, x):
        for _ in range(4):
            x = self.res(*self.args)(x)
        return x
```

Now, if I do the following, everything works out ok and I get **300** trainable parameters:

```
input_layer = Input((128, 128, 3))
conv = basic_conv_stack(10, 3, 1)(input_layer)

model = Model(input_layer, conv)
print (model.summary())
```

Similarly, if I do the following, I get 1,230 trainable parameters:

```
input_layer = Input((128, 128, 3))
conv = basic_residual(10, 3, 1)(input_layer)

model = Model(input_layer, conv)
print (model.summary())
```

However, if I try the basic_module class, I get zero trainable parameters:

```
input_layer = Input((128, 128, 3))
conv = basic_module(10, 3, 1)(input_layer)

model = Model(input_layer, conv)
print (model.summary())
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit to add:

I discovered that the layers used in the call must be initialized in the class's init for things to work properly. So if I change the basic module to this:

```
class basic_module(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides):
        super(basic_module, self).__init__()
        self.clayers = [basic_residual(filters, kernel_size, strides) for _ in range(4)]

    def call(self, x):
        for idx in range(4):
            x = self.clayers[idx](x)
        return x
```

Everything works fine. I don't know *why* this is the case, so I'll leave this question open in case someone can answer the why of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **initialize** the class instances with the required parameter such as `filters`, `kernel_size`, `strides` to the predefined `base_mdoule`. Also, note that these hyper-parameters are related to trainable weights properties.

```
# >>> a = basic_module
# >>> a __main__.basic_module
# >>> a = basic_module(10, 3, 1)
# >>> a 
# >>> <__main__.basic_module at 0x7f6123eed510>

class basic_module(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides):
        super(basic_module, self).__init__()
        self.res = basic_residual # < ---
        self.args = (filters, kernel_size, strides)
    
    def call(self, x):
        for _ in range(4):
            x = self.res(*self.args)(x)
        return x
```